# Keep getting this error message while trying to download an image from Google --> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, google-image-search

Hi guys I am trying to work this code to download images from Google. I am helpless at this point because I have tried everything in my power to figure out what is going on and I still don't know what's up. Please have a look at the code below and the error message that I am getting.

The code runs essentially... But the problem is that it opens the browser, scrolls through the page but then the images are not downloaded and I get an error message...

```
    import requests
    import time
    import urllib
    import argparse
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    from fake_useragent import UserAgent
    from multiprocessing import Pool
    from lxml.html import fromstring
    import os, sys
    import wget

    no=1
    def search(url):
        # Create a browser
        browser = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver')
        browser.implicitly_wait(30)
        # Open the link
        browser.get(url)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        element = browser.find_element_by_tag_name("body")
        # Scroll down
        for i in range(40):
            element.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
            time.sleep(0.1)
        browser.find_element_by_id("smb").click()
        for i in range(10):
            element.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
            time.sleep(0.2)
     
        time.sleep(1)

        # Get page source and close the browser
        source = browser.page_source
        browser.close()

        return source

    def download_image(link):
        global no
        #print link
        # Use a random user agent header
        headers = {"User-Agent": ua.random}

        # Get the image link
        try:
            r = requests.get("https://www.google.com" + link.get("href"), headers=headers)
        except:
            print("Cannot get link.")

        title = fromstring(r.content).findtext(".//title")
        link_url = title.split(" ")[-1]
        print(link_url)

        if link_url.find(".jpg")==len(link_url)-4:
        # Download the image
            wget.download(link_url, str(os.getcwd()) + "/" + query+"/"+str(no)+".jpg")
        no=no+1



    # set stack limit
    sys.setrecursionlimit(1000)
    # get user input and search on google
    query = input("Enter the name you want to search")
    url = "https://www.google.com/search?as_st=y&tbs=isz%3Alt%2Cislt%3Asvga%2Citp%3Aphoto%2Cift%3Ajpg&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=H_-KW6GSHImGoAS3z4DYCA&q=" +query+"&oq="+query+"&gs_l=img.3..0l10.19389.19389.0.21095.1.1.0.0.0.0.113.113.0j1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.img..0.1.111....0.QpKT5Qs8Kdo"
    print(url)
    source = search(url)
    count=1
    # Parse the page source and download pics
    page_text = source.encode('utf-8').decode('ascii', 'ignore')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page_text, "html.parser")
    ua = UserAgent()
    # check directory and create if necessary
    if not os.path.isdir(query):
        os.makedirs(query)
        os.chdir(str(os.getcwd()) + "/" + query)
    # get the links
    links = soup.find_all("a", class_="rg_l")
    for a in links[0:count]:
        try:
            download_image(a)
        except:
            pass
```

and I get this error... I have tried to add `browser.implicitly_wait(30)` to the code but this method does not work either...

```
 selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="smb"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=83.0.4103.116)
```

Could you pleaaaase tell me how to resolve this :( thank you in advance!!

Comment: have you made sure the element with the id `smb` is present through dev console when you open the page yourself? if so - set up an [explicit wait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) to wait for the element to show up.

Comment: it'd be really helpful if you could provide the url of the site you're trying.

Comment: well i searched some random stuff like 'batman'... so the URL that im using is : https://www.google.com/search?as_st=y&tbs=isz%3Alt%2Cislt%3Asvga%2Citp%3Aphoto%2Cift%3Ajpg&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=H_-KW6GSHImGoAS3z4DYCA&q=batman&oq=batman&gs_l=img.3..0l10.19389.19389.0.21095.1.1.0.0.0.0.113.113.0j1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.img..0.1.111....0.QpKT5Qs8Kdo

Comment: there are no elements with the id `smb` in there.